# I'm having problems with rails 4.1 routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-routing

What would be the correct way to convert this **rails 2.1** route,

`map.connect '/ads/:id', :controller=>'ads', :action=>'show'`

To a **rails 4.1** route?

Thanks in advance,
Nathan :-)

Comment: Read this doc first http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to enable full RESTful Routes(create/new/show/delete) to your Adscontroller.Use below one

```
resources :ads
```

If you want to enable only Show method routes to your Adscontroller. Use below one

```
resources :ads, only: :show
```

For further Reference.Please read this documentation : [Resources Routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web)

Comment: why come along hours later and say the same thing as the other answers?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only have the show action for ads, you need to define the route as follows:

```
resources :ads, only: :show
```

This only creates the route `GET ads/:id`. Be sure to read the [Rails documentation on resourceful routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default).